# Odd number proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

> Prove that for every odd number $n$, it holds that $n^2+3$ is not not divisible
>   by $8$.

#### My idea:

Let $n=2k+1$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$, which implies

$$n^2+3=(2k+1)^2+3=4k^2+4k+1+3=4k^2+4k+4$$

How can I conclude that I cannot divide $4k^2+4k+4$ by $8$?

Comment: What if $k$ is even? What if $k$ is odd?

Comment: I got it, thx!!

Comment: This question has nothing whatsoever to do with division algebras, so I removed that tag. Please check the definitions of tags before using them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $k(k+1)$ is divisible by $2$ and $4$ is not divisible by $8$.

Answer (score 0):

There's a much simpler proof using $n^2 \equiv 1 \mod 8$ for odd $n$, which is easy to prove exhaustively.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, a slightly different approach:

If $n^2+3$ is divisible by $8$, then so is $(n-4)^2+3=n^2+3-8n+16$, hence, by induction, $8$ divides $n^2+3$ for at least one $n$ between $-2$ and $2$. But $0^2+3=3$, $(\pm1)^2+3=4$, and $(\pm2)^2+3=7$ are not divisible by $8$.